# Let $R$ be the Ring of all functions in $\mathscr{C}^{0}[0, 1]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, ring-homomorphism

---

---

$\bullet~$ **Problem:** Let $R$ be the *Ring* of all functions in $\mathscr{C}^{0}[0, 1]$. Prove that the map $\varphi : R \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$ \varphi(f) = \int_0^1  f(t) dt \quad \text{for any } f \in \mathscr{C}^{0}([0, 1])$$
is a *Homomorphism* for *additive groups* but not a *Ring Homomorphism*.

---

$\bullet~$ **My Solution:** We are given the ring $R$ of all continuous real-valued functions on the closed interval $[0, 1]$.

According to question let's consider the map
\begin{align*}
    \varphi : &~ R \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
    & f(t) \mapsto \int_{0}^{1} f (t) dt
\end{align*}
$\circ~$ Now we'll check if it's an **Additive Group Homomorphism**.
\begin{align*}
    \varphi(f + g)(t) & = \varphi( f (t) + g(t) )  = \int_{0}^{1} ( f (t) + g (t) )dt\\
    & = \int_{0}^{1} f(t)dt + \int_{0}^{1} g (t)dt\\
    & = \varphi(f) + \varphi(g)
\end{align*}
Hence it is an additive group homomorphism.

$\circ~$ **Edit:** Consider $f(t) = t \in \mathscr{C}^0[0, 1]$ and $g(t) = t^2 \in \mathscr{C}^{0}[0, 1]$ then $(f\cdot g)(t) = t^3 \in \mathscr{C}^0[0, 1] $ .

Now we'll check for the multiplicative one.
\begin{align*}
    \varphi( fg )(t) & = \varphi( f(t) g(t))\\
    & = \int_{0}^{1}  f (t) g (t)  dt\\
    & = \int_0^1 t^3 dt\\
& = \frac{1}{4} \neq \frac{1}{6}\\ 
& =  \int_0^1 t dt \cdot \int_0^1 t^2 dt\\ 
    & = \bigg( \int_{0}^{1} f (t) dt \bigg) \bigg( \int_{0}^{1}  g (t) dt \bigg) \\ 
& = \varphi( f) \cdot \varphi( g )  
\end{align*}
And hence it's clear that, our map is not a ring homomorphism.

---

---

Please check the solution for glitches and give new ideas :)

Comment: I don't see how it is "clear" that the map is not a ring homomorphism. You have to give a specific counterexample where $\varphi(fg)=\varphi(f)\varphi(g)$ doesn't hold.

Comment: Why is your last inequality true? Consider $f(t)=g(t)=t$.

Comment: @Mark I tried to give a counterexample. I tried to show that $\varphi(\lvert f g \lvert ) \leqslant \varphi(\lvert f \rvert) \cdot \varphi(\lvert g \rvert)$

Comment: @SangchulLee Yeah, I got your point.

Comment: @Ralph Clausen But how does it help you? $\leq$ is not enough, maybe there is always an equality? I'll give a hint: show that $\varphi(x^2)\ne \varphi(x)\varphi(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $\phi(|f||g|) \leq \phi(|f|)\phi(|g|)$ is perfectly consistent with the claim that $\phi(|f||g|) = \phi(|f|)\phi(|g|)$. You need to come up with a specific example where equality is violated.